# Cannot grab value within span within h2 within div

Tags: python

I'm trying to grab a VALUE that is in a span within a `h2` tag within a div that has a CLASSNAME

```
<div class="CLASSNAME">
<h2>TITLE</h2>
<h3><span title="VALUE">$VALUE</span></h3>
</div>
```

I'm using this line

```
doc.select('.CLASSNAME').getElementByText('TITLE').next.text
```

But I'm getting error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

I can't understand what's missing?

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't find any function called `getElementByText()` in scrapy's docs. Are you using scrapy?

Comment: simplified-scrapy

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? What’s the result at each step of the search?

Comment: any reason you're not using scrapy? simplified-scrapy looks very young, not widely used ,and doesn't have as well documented API as scrapy.

Comment: but from looking at the examples in https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/get_element.py#L36 it looks like getElementByText gets an HTML tag named that, so you don't have a <title> tag anywhere in the html so its returning None

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to grab a VALUE that is in a span within a h2 tag within a div that has a CLASSNAME

According to your code, the span is within the `h3` tag.
Anyway, don't hesitate to solve the problem stepwise.

```
right_div = response.xpath('//div[@class="CLASSNAME"]')                  
right_value = right_div.xpath(
    './h3/span[contains(@title, "VALUE")]'
    '/text()'
    ).get()
```